Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. Could not find com.serenegiant:common:0.0.3
I encountered the following problem while writing code in Android Studio:

Caused by:
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.


Caused by:
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.serenegiant:common:0.0.3.

What could be the problem?
I added the following to settings.gradle.kts:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven(url = "https://jitpack.io")
        jcenter()
    }

}

rootProject.name = "Project"
include(":app")


It looks like the library is not being loaded.

I added maven(url = "https://jitpack.io") but it failed.

It seems like com.serenegiant:common:0.0.3 was hosted on JCenter which was closed recently. Library's author chose to host it on its own github repository. To continue using it add the following repository:
repositories {
    //...
    maven (url = "https://raw.github.com/saki4510t/libcommon/master/repository/")
}

Also, as you can see, 0.0.3 is really outdated, the most recent version is 9.1.0.
